# Mercurial with KDiff3 -- can it directly expand all folders?

Tags: mercurial, kdiff3

With Mercurial, every time a

```
hg vdiff
```

which invokes kdiff3, there are 2 steps that need to be done:

1) close the pop up that says how many files are diff'ing
2) go to  Directory -> Unfold all Subdirs

Is there a way to skip the step 1 and step 2 and have it automatically expand all folders and show the files?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 check-boxes available on kdiff3 Version 0.9.98 under Settings -> Configure KDiff -> Directory: "Unfold all subdirectories on load" and "Skip directory report status".

Comment: I believe there were older versions of KDiff3 that didn't have this (I remember being frustrated by it), but for modern versions, this is totally the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hrm, that'll be entirely up to kdiff3, but if you can find a command line option that starts kdiff3 out in expanded mode you'll can tweak the vdiff string in the configuration lines for the [ExtdiffExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension), which is the feature someone has configured for you.  That can be configured in any `hgrc` which can be per-repo (`.hg/hgrc`), per-user (`~/.hgrc`), or system-wide (`/etc/mercurial'hgrc`).  If you don't recall setting it up it's probably in the system-wide location.

If you want to see exactly where as setting is coming from in a recent version of Mercurial you can use the command:

```
hg --debug showconfig
```

look for kdiff3 there and you'll find exactly what file and line to tweak.

Comment: Yeah, that's hugely handy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible, as it's not in kdiff3's [command line options](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html), and there's no config item for it as seen from `kdiff3 --confighelp`.

I guess you can hack the source. It's Qt so it can't be hard, can it?

(BTW Beyond Compare has -expandall option that does exactly that. I don't want to sound like I get commission from Scooter Software, but BC is literally beyond any diff/merge tool that I've seen. There's one thing that kdiff3 can but BC cannot, though: 3-directory comparison.)